# How to split an array of characters without using any basic function

Tags: c++

I have this function: `int split(char* str, char s)`, so how to split the `str` without using `strtok()` or other functions?

E.g: `str = "1,2,3,4,5", s = ','`

After `split(str, s)`, output will be:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Sorry guys, the int return -1 if str == NULL and return 1 if str != NULL.

Comment: consider the string as a sequence of `linked` characters and upon finding `,` you need to move on to printing in new line

Comment: You're searching for `join`?

Comment: Is this C or C++?  The function wants a `char*` versus a `string`.

Comment: @TheObscureQuestion C++

Comment: @Czipperz I know that there are reasons to use a `char*` instead of a `string` in C++, but this seems a bit weird.

Comment: @BaratheonStannis what does the int return mean?

Answer (score 3):

How about this? I'm not sure what the int return type means in the function so I made it the count of splits.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int split(char* str, char s) {
    int count = 0;
    while (*str) {
        if (s == *str) {
            putchar('\n');
            count++;
        } else {
            putchar(*str);
        }
        str++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't write code for years, but that should do?

```
while (*str) // as long as there are more chars coming...
{
  if (*str == s) printf('\n');  // if it is a separator, print newline
  else printf('%c',*str);       // else print the char
  str++;     // next char
}
```

Comment: Using printf to print a single character is inefficient.

Comment: yes, this wasn't about being efficient. normally I would collect the result in a new char * and print it at the end. It was just supposed to illustrate the concept.

Comment: When you give inefficient code to newbies, they put it in production without a second thought.  Later, when they learn how to do it better, some manager will prevent them from changing the working code.  So it's better not to suggest it.

Answer (score 0):

```
string split(const char* str, char s) {
    std::string result = str;
    std::replace(result.begin(), result.end(), s, '\n');
    result.push_back('\n'); // if you want a trailing newline
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Return type is an `int`, so I'm guessing that he wants to print out the split strings from the function.

Comment: @TheObscureQuestion: It's possible.  I prefer to let the caller of the function say `cout << split(...)` or whatever.  Keep I/O separate from transformation.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Dang functional programmers xD

Answer (score 0):

Another approach...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void split(char* str, char s){
    while(*str){
        if(*str==s){
            cout << endl;
        }else{
            cout << *str;
        }
        str++;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main(){

   split((char*)"herp,derp",',');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

and another one with iterator

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



int main() {
    string s="1,2,3,4,5";
    char   cl=',';
    for(string::iterator it=s.begin();it!=s.end();++it) 
      if (*it == cl) 
        cout << endl; 
      else cout << *it;

    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/RPrls7